# How to import projects (i.e from github) to my application

Tags: java, maven, github, import, javaparser

So I have been working on a project where I need to process some Java code. To do this I decided to use JavaParser.

On their website [JavaParser](http://javaparser.org/), I see a 'Getting Started' guide that explains how to include JavaParser in Maven and Gradle but as I am not using either, what I think I need to do is get some `javaparser.jar` and add that to my classpath?

My question is, I couldn't find anywhere to download this .jar file on the [JavaParser website](http://javaparser.org/)  or [JavaParser GitHub](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser), so is this the right way to do this? Should I be cloning projects I want to make use of and create my own jar files? Do I need to be using Maven?

I ended up finding the jar file on a third party website instead of finding it on any official JavaParser page and that gave me the impression I was doing something wrong.

All answers appreciated!
-James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually download the necessary jars from public maven repositories. As I see you need these two:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.tomassetti/java-symbol-solver-core

Pick a version you like and on its page there is a download jar link.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. By the way I strongly recommend you to learn one of those project management tools.